# Задание ширины контейнера по ширине самого широкого элемента

Tags: html, css, html5, вёрстка, css3

Можно ли только средствами CSS автоматически выравнивать сгруппированные элементы по максимальной ширине одного из них? Например:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>111</span><br>
  <span>22222222</span><br>
  <span>333</span><br>
  <span>444444</span>
</div>
```

Здесь надо найти самый широкий `span` (это будет `22222222`) и остальные `span`'ы выровняться по его ширине.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это возможно, но только надо ваш контейнер обернуть ещё одним (для горизонтального центрирования) и использовать flexbox. Далее теги `br` в разметке не пригодятся:

```css
span {
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* Для горизонтального выравнивания */
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  /* display: inline-flex чтобы занимал ширину по контенту */
  /* Значение align-items: stretch по умолчанию, заставляет все элементы растягиваться */ 
  display: inline-flex;
  /* Чтобы располагался "в стоблик" а не "в строчку" по умолчанию */
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span>111</span>
    <span>22222222</span>
    <span>333</span>
    <span>444444</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.b {
    text-align: center;
}

.b-inner {
    display: inline-block; /* ширина равная максимальной ширине содержимого в span */
}

.b-inner > span {    
   display: block; /* делаем ширину 100%, которая ограничена родителем с display: inline-block */
   border: 2px solid black;
   border-bottom: none;
}

.b-inner > span:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
    <div class="b-inner">
        <span>111</span>
        <span>22222222</span>
        <span>333</span>
        <span>444444</span>
        <span>55555555555555555555555</span>
    </div>
</div>
```